# Cannot invoke 'atan2' with an argument list of type '(Double)'というエラーが出ます。

Tags: swift, ios

Swiftにて以下の様にコードを書いたところ、Cannot invoke 'atan2' with an argument list of type '(Double)'というエラーが出ます。

```
let with = 4.0
let pWidth = 0.6
let r = (with/2) - pWidth
let atan = atan2((pWidth / 2) / r)//ここにエラーが出ます。
```

これはどの様な原因で起こっているのでしょうか。
型による問題が起きているという事でしょうか。
すいません、宜しくお願い致します。

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`atan2`は座標(x, y)と座標(0, 0)を結んだ線の角度θを求める関数なので、引数が１つ足りないというエラーです。
この場合は`atan((pWidth / 2) / r)`で充分かと思われます。

Comment: 大変ありがとうございます！！atan2自体の使用方法が間違っていたのですね。
非常に参考になりました。

Comment: `atan` の引数の中で除算するくらいなら素直に `atan2(pWitdth, r*2)` のほうが除算を排除出来て安全で高速だと思うっす